# zk-maven project: in .zul file, window tag's apply attribute got "cannot be resolved to a type" error hint

Tags: java, maven, zk

I am trying to create a zk-maven project from scratch.
However, when I want to add [apply="sphinxSpeechRecog"] attribute inside the "window" tag, the eclipse IDE gives me an error-hint floating dialog saying :"sphinxSpeechRecog cannot be resolved to a type".
I already check that the path of my class is correct.

I have tried to clean up the project but it didn't help.

the .zul:

```
<?page title="sphinx" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul">
<window title="sphinx" border="normal" apply="sphinxSpeechRecog">
</window>
</zk>
```

the .java:

```
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.SelectorComposer;

public class sphinxSpeechRecog extends SelectorComposer<org.zkoss.zk.ui.Component>{


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be caused by the fact that I'm missing the "src/main/java" package when I create a blank maven project.

- 1. On the project, right click "Property" then switch to the "Source"
     tab.
  2. Click on "sphinx/src/main/java"(which is red-marked now) item and then click "Edit...".
  3. In the popup dialog, type in "src/main/java". And then, click "Next"(NOT "Finish").
  4. At the "Inclusion patterns:" click "Add", and then in the popup dialog type in "src/main/java".
  5. Click "Finish" and then click "Apply and Close".
  6. Now the src/main/java package appears in the Project Explorer!!!
  7. New a class named "SphinxSpeechRecog" under the "src/main/java".sphinx path.
  8. Go to the .zul file and type in {apply="sphinx.SphinxSpeechRecog"}. The red underline will not appear
     now.

Referenced solution: [with printscreen pictures(step-by-step)](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_27828109/article/details/78083584)

Answer (score 0):

In the zul file, you should also apply the java package in the Window tag.

Change

```
<window title="sphinx" border="normal" apply="sphinxSpeechRecog">
```

To (For example your package is com.a.b)

```
<window title="sphinx" border="normal" apply="com.a.b.sphinxSpeechRecog">
```

Comment: Thank you, but this step wouldn't help. Before you answered my question, I didn't have the com.a.b package at my project directory tree. After I see your answer, I intentionally add a package named "acom", and I put my .java file inside the package; then, I change the code in .zul to what you have suggested, but it still doesn't work. The "acom" shows red underline. The error message now is "acom cannot be resolved to a type".